# Why does skype shut down by itself?

Tags: 11.04, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skype 2.2.0.25 keeps going off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45278/skype-2-2-0-25-keeps-going-off)

So I installed the brand-new 11.04 and, of course, Skype beta 2.2. However, when I leave my computer idle for some time, Skype just shuts down and then I have to open it up and login again.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Answer: Because it's a Microsoft Product.

Comment: Can you post the output of your Skype log? (It should be in ~/.Skype), and what happens when you run Skype from the terminal?

Comment: Are you sure it did shutdown, and not crash?

Comment: This is duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/45278/skype-2-2-0-25-keeps-going-off also on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/288937/my-skype-keeps-on-crashing-when-i-run-skype-and-try-to-login