# Skype 2.2.0.25 keeps switching off

Tags: skype

After my computer crashed, my Skype doesn't stay on any more. I start it, the window opens up, but after 5 seconds Skype exits again by itself. I already reinstalled it four times.

Comment: Same thing here

Answer (score 18):

It [crashed for everyone](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2074186/skype-suffers-disastrous-crash-users-question-microsoft-buyout). Apparently on Linux you keep getting `Aborted` on the console upon logging in. What fixes the problem is removing shared.xml from settings directory. Thus on Ubuntu it's:

```
rm ~/.Skype/shared.xml
```

BTW. bit off topic here, but just for the sake of it

On Windows remove:

```
c:\Documents and Settings\*user*\Application Data\Skype\shared.xml
```

On OSX:

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/shared.xml
```

Update: There is [official acknowledgment of the issue from Skype](http://heartbeat.skype.com/2011/05/problems_signing_into_skype_an.html).

Comment: looks like it works, I'v also removed and reinstalled Skype.

Comment: re-install wasn't necessary for me

Comment: yes, not necessary! I did the same on another machine, works without re-install.

Comment: might help for some, but did not help me, using 12.0.4.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting `shared.xml` file in your home directory `~/.Skype/shared.xml`

This command in the terminal will remove it `rm ~/.Skype/shared.xml`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem after the recent unity-update. Removing `$HOME/.Skype/shared.xml` helps it.