# Skype aborted when starting

Tags: skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skype 2.2.0.25 keeps going off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45278/skype-2-2-0-25-keeps-going-off)

Hi.

I got a problem with skype.

When I turn it on, it's not showing. I tried from command line and here's what I got:

nicolas@Foundation:~$ skype
Aborted

How can I solve that?