# Skype is closed after logging in

Tags: skype

I installed Skype using Ubuntu Software Center. When I logged in to Skype, it was automatically closed. I tried to remove and reinstall it but the problem is still there. How to fix it?

**Update:**

Log output after login.

```
hieund@hieund:/etc$ skype
Fatal: ASSERT: "interface->childCount() == children.count()" in file adaptor.cpp, line 200
Aborted
hieund@hieund:/etc$
```

Comment: Try to start it via terminal, when it is closed you can see some error output.

Comment: where is it located? what command to start please?

Comment: Open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and just give the command: `skype` Upate your question with your output. And please give more info beside that output. ie, your Ubuntu version, your OS architecture (32bit or 64bit), your Skype version, etc.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but.. any use? http://askubuntu.com/questions/45278/skype-2-2-0-25-keeps-going-off

Comment: @Caesium: I already tried it before I post this question. I tried to use "rm ~/.Skype/shared.xml" but nothing changes.

Comment: Ok. Worth posting info like that in the original question, always useful to know what you've tried so we don't post useless info :)

Comment: @Caesium: Sorry, I'll do it in the next question. :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message leads me to this Ubuntu bug via Google..

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt-at-spi/+bug/890240

I'm surprised it hasn't gotten more attention if it is affecting Skype.. it may help if you chime in with your experience :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

http://www.filchiprogrammer.com/blog/2011/10/30/skype-issue-assert-interface-childcount-children-count/

> I googled this for a solution and by just typing,
>
> ```
> export QT_ACCESSIBILITY=0
> ```
>
> fixes the problem.
>
> Hope this helps to anyone setting up skype in Ubuntu 11.10.

Works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Skype 4.3 no longer supported on 32 bit, so microsoft kills it when you log in.(Silly).
Solution: make skype a "higher" version:
**sudo sed -i 's/4.3.0.37/8.3.0.37/' /usr/bin/skype**
It replaces the version number in the binary for a higher one to work around the forced incompatibility.
Make sure that you have the same version 4.3.0.37 by calling skype --version or update the command accordingly.
Thanks to YuriyKuzin.

Comment: oh that is too funny...  only needed this on my 32-bit system.  my 64-bit system seems to work fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually, the only thing that worked for me on Ubuntu 10.04 after trying to apply the advice of I don't know how many people, was to go to `sound device configuration` right after starting `Skype` and **make a test call before any connected contact appeared** on the screen (you have to be fast!!).

From there on, I can suspend the test call without even waiting for the lady to speak, and `Skype` keeps working. I found this solution merely by accident.