# Skype in Ubuntu 14.04 can't detect speakers, microphone, or camera

Tags: 14.04, sound, skype, webcam, microphone

**Problem**

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and in Skype's audio/video settings, it says "No device found" under each of speakers, microphone, and camera.

**Relevent or possibly relevant information**

- All three - speakers, mic, and camera - work in Skype on my Windows 10 partition, and they also work in the Ubuntu partition with programs other than Skype.
- PulseAudio is installed and configured correctly. In fact, it's configured the same way as it was on my old laptop, which also ran Ubuntu 14.04 and on which Skype detected everything fine.
- Computer: Asus X555Q
- Skype version: 8.11.0.4

Any ideas? Let me know if you need me to provide more info/screenshots.

Comment: What devices are selected in Skype Settings?  My experience is that it sometimes picks up HDMI audio instead of regular sound card, and doesn't detect webcams at all (though I haven't tried a webcam since version 8 came out for Linux).

Comment: No devices are detected so none are selected. Although now that you mention HDMI audio, that does show up in PulseAudio. I did disable it, but to no avail.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with Skype 8.20.0.9 on Ubuntu 17.10. My speakers, microfone and webcam are working fine in all other applications, only in Skype they're not even detected. I can't believe they haven't fixed this yet, considering [people have already reported this issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_callms-skype_audioms/skype-for-linux-8901-no-mic-speakers-or-camera/1ff0703a-0b81-4a91-8c0e-a84a05ed73cd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's a workaround: Just download and install Skype 4.3 (https://skype.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu).

However, the good people at Microsoft, in order to protect us from a suboptimal user experience, have deemed it prudent to make older versions of Skype immediately force-quit when you try to log in (and in their beneficent wisdom, they don't sully the graceful exit with any sort of abstruse technical mumbo jumbo like "Please download the latest version").

Luckily, you can trick them by changing the version number in the binary (this solution comes from [Nicholas Odicoh](https://askubuntu.com/a/981579/773355)):

```
sudo sed -i 's/4.3.0.37/8.3.0.37/' /usr/bin/skype
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this?  I'm surprised you can still download a version that Microsoft won't allow to log in any more...

Comment: I did try this, and it does work. The one downside is that for some reason my contacts list is empty (but only on this Ubuntu installation; I can still see my contacts list on my Windows installation).

Comment: Your contact list is empty because that client isn't allowed to contact the database at the Microsoft end, because you're using an outdated and unsupported version of Skype.  It'll stay empty, if I correctly understand how this works.